# Want to know apiPassword scope and lifecycle which is returned from /v2/login_information api call

Tags: docusignapi

Want to consume DocuSign rest API for production, what is scope and lifecycle *apiPassword*  which is returned from /v2/login_information API call.

Is it encrypted password if it is then which algorithm is used to encode it

Not able to find any reference Documentation for it below is returning 404 for Doc for this API

https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Authentication&tags=Authentication&operations=login&mode=basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the legacy authentication method. You should not use that but instead consider using OAuth which is more secure. The ApiPassword never expired and as such - is a security risk.

Comment: Thanks, Inbar for the quick response, are you aware of any limitations with rest API usage and the number of calls we can make in an hour or day?

Comment: typically it's 1000/hour (per account). In rare occasions this number can be increased by calling support. I would first look into your design and how to reduce the number of API calls

Answer (score 0):

An API password cannot be decrypted into the actual password, it is a token that can be used for authentication.

The API password does not change when the account password is reset, and it does not expire naturally. The API password can be revoked by accessing My Profile > Connected Apps > Revoke.

As Inbar states, Legacy Header authentication is discouraged, and documentation for it has been retired.

Comment: Thanks, Drew for the quick response, are you aware of any limitations with rest API usage and the number of calls we can make in an hour or day?

Comment: The default API limit is 1000 calls per hour, refreshing on the hour every hour. You can track your consumption and the next reset time using the X-RateLimit-Remaining and X-RateLimit-Reset headers that are returned in each API call. The -reset header is a unix timestamp.